# Use a graph to find the range of the function on the given interval

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I have tried to resolve this problem but site shows error in my answer
I have the fucntion $f(x)=1/x^2$

Use a graph to find the range of the function on the given interval below: 
$-3 \le x \le 3$.

Well, I do know the range doesn't exist for $0$
and my guess is that I have to get results between $-3$ and $3$, because I have $x^2$ the results will be positive so I think the solution should be
$(0,9]$ or $0<x \le 9$ but the site says not correct.

Could you please help me with the problem?
Thanks.

Jose

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: When $x=3, f(x) = (1/9),$ rather than $9.\;$ Also, as $\;x \rightarrow 0^+,\;f(x) \rightarrow +{\infty}.$

Answer (score 1):

The question asks you to use a graph.

Have you tried looking at the graph of $y=f(x)$?

[image]

By examining the graph for our domain $-3 \leq x \leq 3$, it should be pretty clear that the range is $y \geq f(3)$ as the $y$ value never falls below $f(3)$ in our domain.

Remember that our function is $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$, not $f(x) = {x^2}$. So $f(3)$ evaluates to $\frac{1}{9}$, not $9$.

Your range should also be given using $y$, not $x$, as the range represents a set of $y$ values.

Here's another way to think about it: consider what happens to $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$. As $x$ becomes smaller, so does $x^2$. And fractions become larger in value as their denominators become smaller (for example, take $\frac{1}{0.01} = 100$). So as $x$ approaches $0$, $f(x)$ approaches infinity, i.e. $\lim_{x\to0} f(x) = \infty$.